# activeadmin with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

Working on a legacy server with Ruby 1.8.7 installed, I'd like to use Activeadmin in my Rails 3.0.20 app.

Can anyone tell me what is the last version of Activeadmin that is compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveAdmin was actively tested against REE (which is a variant of Ruby 1.8.7) until v0.5.1. There seems to be a consent of the authors to keep supporting 1.8.7 until explicit notice though (as documented in [#1967](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1967)).

Comment: Thank you Holger. 0.5.1 works under 1.8.7 indeed. 0.6.2 on the other hand doesn't

Comment: You might want to open an issue on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues) then.

Comment: Ruby 1.8 is no longer supported by Active Admin because 1.8 itself is no longer maintained.